# On iPad Safari Dev Tool Getting Error "Refused to execute JavaScript URL"

Tags: visualforce, javascript, http, ipad

Over the weekend the following formula field building a link stopped working on iPad.

`IF (ShowCustomLink__c, HYPERLINK("/apex/MyVfPage?id="&Id + "&var1=val1" + "&var2="&Name, IMAGE("/resource/ResourceWithButtonImages", "Alt Text"),"_self"), NULL)`

This formula field generates the following markup:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ontouchstart="javascript:{ var openEvent = 
$A.get('e.force:navigateToURL');  openEvent.setParams({'url':'/apex/MyVfPage?
id=[SfIdHere]&amp;var1=val1&amp;var2=val2'});openEvent.fire();}" data-aura-
rendered-by="394:282;a"><img src="/resource/ResourceWithButtonImages" 
alt="Alt Text" border="0"></a>
```

Using my Mac and Safari dev tools to inspect and view the browser console I see the following two errors.

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension: 
https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.na30.visual.force.com
https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/".

Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content 
Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension: 
https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.na30.visual.force.com 
https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/".
```

I brushed up on my understanding of Content Security Policy directive script-src and determined that the markup generated by the formula field `HYPERLINK` function is causing the violations by using the inline `ontouchstart` event and the `javascript:` in the href attribute. I suspect SF changed the Content Security Policy header at some point causing this to break. Any suggestions on a workaround to this problem or another way to build the hyperlink so it is compliant with the CSP header?

Comment: Spring '17 was pushed out this weekend (at least it was to one of my orgs) and is likely the cause given the timing. Cause could be violation in your code is finally enforced or a bug. The update also broke `<lightning:select>` when used in `lightning out` as well....(unfortunately there is no-one to tell these issues to) No an answer but a spot for you to start investigating.....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code is not mine so I place the blame on SF but at the end of the day I can't dictate to them to change it. I need a way to fix asap instead of waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to create a Custom Link and add it to the layout. Below are specific steps on how to accomplish. The advantage of this is it outputs a simple anchor HTML element defining only the href attribute and does not use inline javascript. This did change the look and feel some from how it worked before but I believe it is acceptable given the circumstances.

1. Login to you org
2. Go to **[User Name]** > **Setup**
3. In left hand pane choose **Create** > **Objects**
4. Locate the object which you would like to have a hyperlink on and click on its name
5. Scroll down to **Buttons, Links, and Actions**
6. Click **New Button or Link** button
7. You can give the button a name, use merge fields as well as determine the behavior of how the browser opens the hyperlink.
   NOTE: if the URL is pointing to a resource on your org use a relative path starting with "/...". E.g. for a VF page would look something like this "/apex/MyVFPage".
8. Save the button once you have configured it with the correct settings.
9. Open a record of the same object type which you are adding the custom button link to
10. Click **Edit Layout** from the links in the upper right portion of the view
11. Choose **Custom Links** from the left hand side pane
12. You should see the hyperlink you just created and be able to drag it to the **Custom Links** section of the layout
13. Save
14. The new custom link should appear after the custom and standard object fields section.

Answer (score 0):

Since inline javascript execution is a security vulnerability issue, salesforce has stopped it's support to this 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: I understand it is a vulnerability, the issue is that SF controls the output of HYPERLINK function which includes javascript in the link. What that article appears to say to me is that they find it acceptable to break their own code and don't have any intention of updating it to comply with new security measures.

Comment: Ian, 
The solution which you have mentioned above works, but this will not help me in making these custom links available in search layouts and reporting.

Comment: Are you having a specific issue with search layout links? I haven't come across any issue regarding search layouts and/or reporting yet. Maybe post a question with the issue you have encountered?